# Can we consider 3 triangles in case of congruency

Tags: triangles

Q: The perpendicular bisector of the sides of a triangle AB meet at I. Prove that: IA = IB = IC

[image]

By considering two triangles:

We need to prove that
$$
I A=I B=I C
$$
Proof:
In $\Delta$ BID and $\Delta$ CID
$\mathrm{BD}=\mathrm{DC}$ (given)
$\angle B D I=\angle C D I=90^{\circ}(A D$ is perpendicular bisector of $B C)$
$\mathrm{BC}=\mathrm{BC}$ (common)
By SAS postulate of congruent triangles
$$
\Delta \mathrm{BID} \cong \triangle \mathrm{CID}
$$
The corresponding parts of the congruent triangles are congruent
Therefore IB $=I C$
Similarly, In $\Delta \mathrm{CIE}$ and $\triangle \mathrm{AIE}$
$$
\mathrm{CE}=\mathrm{AE} \text { (given) }
$$
$\angle \mathrm{CEI}=\angle \mathrm{AEI}=90^{\circ}(\mathrm{AD}$ is perpendicular bisector of $\mathrm{BC})$
IE = IE (common)
By SAS postulate of congruent triangles
$$
\Delta \mathrm{CIE} \cong \triangle \mathrm{AIE}
$$
The corresponding parts of the congruent triangles are congruent
Therefore IC = IA
Thus, IA = IB = IC

But , I want to know if there is a way I can do this a less lengthier & by considering 3 triangles at once or if considering 3 triangles is even true or possible to do so

Comment: The image is very misleading. Perpendicular bisectors in general are not this "neat". For instance, the perpendicular bisector of the side $BC$ does not necessarily intersect $A$; the perpendicular bisector intersects $A$ iff $\angle B = \angle C$. Hence, your statement "$AD$ is perpendicular bisector of $BC$" is generally false.

Comment: What does it mean by "considering two triangles"?

Comment: @Mehmer The way I have done by considering two triangles. Proving two triangles congruent & then going onto another two. My Q is can we prove the 3 triangles all at once as congruent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As VTand has pointed out, your diagram is very misleading. Here is a less misleading version:

[image]

The common intersection point doesn't even have to lie inside the triangle:

[image]

However, one way you can prove it faster is to draw the circle passing through $A,B,C$. The three sides of the triangle are chords of this circle, and are therefore perpendicularly bisected by radii of the circle. That is, the perpendicular bisector of each side must be a radius, and therefore passes through the circle center. Thus the circle center is their common intersection point, and is by its definition equidistant from $A, B, C$.

Whether this truly counts as a shorter demonstration is debatable. After all, it depends on a couple results about circles: that you can find a unique circle through any three non-collinear points in the plane, and that the perpendicular bisectors of chords of a circle are radii.

Comment: Thank you very much.